# Train MSE becomes smaller then test mse when model becomes morgen complex

Tags: r, cross-validation, lasso, ridge-regression, mse

Iam doing a ridge and lasso regression and choose my lambdas via cross validation with K = 5 and K = 10.

I do this with 3 data sets because i want to analize if more variables yield to a better prediction.

1. data set = my data set
2. data set = my data set + polynomials of continous variables to the power of 4 + all possible interaction terms to the order of 2 of my data set and polynomials (V1*V2 + V1*V3 ...)
3. data set = the same like 2. data set but i use interaction term to the order of 3 (V1*V2*V3 + V1*V4*V5 + ....)

Iam a little bit confused about the results that i get.

For the first data set i get for both methods higher train mse then test mse
For the second data set i get for both methods smaller train mse then test mse
For the third data set i get for both methods also smaller train mse then test mse.

Also the results for K = 5 and K = 10 have no difference

What could be an explenation for such results?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Shouldn't the MSE training always be lower than the MSE test? So cases 2. and 3. should be the normal case. Could it have been pure luck in the first case? What happens if you use other training and test data?

Comment: I suggest that for your first method you try it with different seeds for you random split (your train test split) of your data and plot the distribution of MSEs you get. See if the difference between your train and test MSE is actually significant in the context of the distribution of the MSE because remember, your MSEs at present are just point estimates.

Comment: @Martin please do not use answers for commenting questions.

Comment: @Dan but if i used different seeds how can i compare the results? What is the explenation for train mse < test mse?

Comment: @DimaKu the training MSE *should* be lower than the test MSE because that is the dataset that you are optimizing over, i.e. seen data.

Comment: @DimaKu regarding finding the distribution of the MSE, I was just suggesting you do it for the first case to establish if the difference was significant. But I guess you could do it by taking different random splits of your training set, similar to a CV but with many more folds and allow them to overlap. You just want to get more than a point estimate for the training MSE so you can see if it is significantly higher or if it is just higher by chance. But I'm not suggestion you compare your different models using a distribution of MSEs.

Comment: @Dan  i tried different seeds and sometimes  the train mse is sometimes smaller and  sometimes higher then test mse

Comment: @DimaKu so sounds like it's just a consequence of noise inherent to your process. i.e. the difference between train and test MSE is too small to meaningful call one bigger than the other.

Comment: @Dan: your last comment sounds like an answer. Do you want to post it as such?

Comment: @StephanKolassa sure, added it. I didn't want to because I'm not suggesting a rigorous statistical test in it which maybe someone else can add...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your training MSE *should* be lower than your test MSE because you are optimizing for a low training MSE whereas your test MSE is calculated over data unseen during the optimization.

So the question is why is your training MSE higher in your first case. I would counter this question by asking, is it really significantly higher?

Remember that your MSE is just a point estimate sampled from a distribution of possible MSEs and which exact data made it into your training set vs your test set affects this point estimate. I suggest you try and get an idea of what the underlying distribution looks like so that you can try an ascertain if the training MSE is significantly larger than the test MSE.

One way to do this is to take your training set and randomly select say 80% of it for a new sub-training set (maybe sample with repetition at this point). Then out of what's left, you have a new sub-test set. Record the MSE for both this sub-training and sub-test sets. then repeat this process many times and plot the distribution.

After that you need to decide if the difference in your original observation is significant. Maybe someone here can suggest a theoretically sound way to do this but I would just look at the variance of the distribution, or maybe the standard error and see how that compares to your observed difference. Then just use judgement to decide if there is really a problem here or not.

Comment: +1. [Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good!](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352)